# StreamBuilder snapshot.data.length

Tags: android, ios, flutter, function, google-play

```
buildProductList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      initialData: productBloc.getAll(),
      stream: productBloc.getStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        return snapshot.data.length>0? buildProductListItems(snapshot) : Center(child: Text("Oops.."),);},
    );
  }
```

i was try "?" and"!" didn't work
example,
snapshot.data?.length>0?

snapshot.!data.length>0?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04cp3.png)
didn t work

here error mes.

The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. (Documentation)  Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'.

Answer (score 3):

check first if data is List or not like this

```
List myFun(snapshot) {

return (snapshot.data is List)? snapshot.data as List : []

}
```

now you can use it like this

```
myFun(snapshot).isNotEmpty? buildProductListItems(snapshot) : Center(child: Text("Oops.."),);
```

Answer (score 0):

try
`snapshot.data!.length`

notice the `!`

and also read this for clarification: [Dart Null Safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety#:%7E:text=The%20Dart%20language%20now%20supports,into%20edit%2Dtime%20analysis%20errors.)

Comment: like i said didn t work bro

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I don't think your problem is with the null safety or the `!`,

your error is related to the fact that you can't call `.length` on a dynamic object.

so to fix that (obviously after you put the `!` after the `data`),
you should give a type to your snapshot parameter.

so for example if your data is a list, you should do this:

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot){
        return snapshot.data!.length>0? buildProductListItems(snapshot) : Center(child: Text("Oops.."),);},
    );
```

I hope this solves your problem.